Stop List From Covering Background Color
I'm making what (I think) is a fairly simple screen in SwiftUI, but I'm stuck. I want a list that respects the safe area, and a background that should not. However, the list seems to cover the background. If I scroll all the way down, I can see that the background is in fact there.
My question is, how would I get the dark background color at the bottom to show to the left of the "hello"? Setting the row background doesn't seem to have any effect.

struct ScrollSheetView: View {
    @State var upperBound = 0
    @State var valueRange = Array(stride(from: 1, to: 100, by: 1))
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.mainBackground
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                List(valueRange, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("hello")
                }
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .listRowBackground(Color.mainBackground)
            }
        }
    }
}


You should put the .listRowBackground(Color.mainBackground) inside the list.

@Radioactive THANK YOU! If you add your solution as an answer I'll mark it accepted; worked perfectly!

Your .listRowBackground(Color.mainBackground) should be aplied to the content inside the List. It shouldn't be applied to the List itself.
ZStack {
    Color.mainBackground
        .ignoresSafeArea()
          
    VStack {
        List(valueRange, id: \.self) { index in
            Text("hello")
                .listRowBackground(Color.mainBackground)
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}

